# this.tokenGetter is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I am trying to send a post request on Angular project, it works fine on localhost, but when I deploy it on Server it gave me an error:

> this.tokenGetter is not a function

Here is the post request code:

```
dataExportViaFilterId(model: Model) {
    return this.http.post<DataExportResponseDTO>(`${constants.DATAEXPORT_BASE_URL}`, model);
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I have encountered the same issue and I just had to remove this piece of code inside the providers option in app module:

```
   { provide: JWT_OPTIONS, useValue: JWT_OPTIONS }
```